# Calculate Date Differences in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am actually a SAS Coder and trying to figure out how to calculate the date difference on SQL. Here is the scenario- i'll be executing the same query on every monday, wednesday, and friday and it will look for customers who opened account in last couple of days. Technically when i execute the query on monday, code has to look for customers who opened their account on friday, sat, and sunday, and when i execute it on Wednesday code has to look for customers who opened on monday and tuesday, and when i execute it on friday code has to look for customers who opened their account on wednesday and thursday. Any suggestions please. I want to automate the script so any help is highly appreciated. I am currently using SQL WorkBench to move my scripts from sas to SQL

Answer (score 0):

Really you're just looking for customers created in the last two days or 3 days depending on the day of the week, and not including those created today:

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
WHERE 
  createdate >=
    CASE 
      WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 2 -- when Monday
      THEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), interval 3 day) -- then today minus 3 days
      ELSE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), interval 2 day) -- else today minus two days
    END
  AND createdate < CURDATE()
```

Comment: Yes, i'll be looking for the past dates because the tables are updated everyday after 8:pm so there wont be any today's data. Thank you for your response, i'll check and let you know

Comment: Curdate is the current date, without any time information. You can conceive it to be at midnight. Thus this query looks for createdate (that can have a time also) between midnight 2 or 3 days ago, and midnight today (midnight is the first thing that happens on any given day). If run on Monday, Wednesday or Friday, this query hence gives date ranges of >= midnight some days ago, and less than midnight today I.e, only dates from yesterday, day before (and maybe day before before) can show

Answer (score 0):

I would create a script that saves a variable as the date of whatever the last time you ran the script so that it could be used on anyday. Pseudo code will be placed in [brackets like so] because I'm unsure of some of your preferences or naming conventions.

```
DECLARE @MyLastDate [Data Type for persisting date]
DECLARE @TodaysDate [Data Type for persisting date]

if @MyLastDate == null {
SET @MyLastDate = [Todays Date]
}

SELECT * FROM [myTableName]
WHERE customerOpenDate BETWEEN '@MyLastDate' AND '@TodaysDate'

SET @MyLastDate = [Todays Date]
```

I may be missing some steps since I am missing some details, but this logic should be enough to get you going.